# How do I conditionally show or hide fields on a Layout in Filemaker 14 Advanced?

Tags: database, forms, layout, show, filemaker

I'm new to creating Layouts in Filemaker (I'm not using the latest version; am using Filemaker 14 Advanced instead), and I need to know: How can I conditionally/programmatically hide and show drop-down menus on the Layout, based on a selection in another drop-down menu? For instance: Let's say I have a drop-down menu called "Race," and it has three selections: "Human, Vampire, Werewolf." If I choose "Human," I want another drop-down menu called "Class" to appear; if I choose "Vampire," I want a different drop-down menu, called "Clans," to appear instead; if I choose Werewolf, then I want a drop-down menu called "Tribes" to appear. How can I engineer this using Filemaker's built-in language, or is there some other way to do it? Step-by-step instructions and/or code, please; like I said, I'm really, really new to this and to databases in general. Thanks!

Comment: See: http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5833/kw/conditional%20value%20list/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ4MTI5MzczNS9zaWQvUmtXRypINW4%3D -- Note: this is not really question about programming. I suggest you join one of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I'll join one of the FM forums and check there. Unfortunately, the place you pointed me toward only talks about conditional value lists, which isn't what I'm after. Thanks for that, though - it might come in handy later. :-)

Comment: If you meant "show/hide" literally, you would have to place 3 instances of the same field onto the layout, each with its own value list attached, and hide 2 of them conditionally.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I want to do. However, I'm stuck because I don't know FM's internal scripting language from Adam. If it were javascript or AppleScript, I'd be golden, and could write the script blindfolded. But FM's scripting language is weird, and alien to me. So I'm trying to see if someone can spell it out for me, step by step, how to write the "calculation" that attaches to the "Hide Object When" setting of the Inspector.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Wow, that was actually really trivial! Thanks for the pointers, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally hide layout objects by putting a calculation in the Hide Object When blank in the Behavior section of the Data tab on the Inspector palette.

That said, there are relational ways to have your dropdowns change their contents based selections in other fields. That is a lot more flexible, but (of course) more complex. What you want to set up is called a Dynamic Value list and is based on the values in a related table, filtered by the choices you made in the previous fields.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. What I need help with is writing the script — the calculation — itself. I'm completely new to FM's scripting language, and I'm a bit lost when it comes to the right commands for getting/setting layout objects states and so forth. Could you maybe help me out with an example showing how if a value is selected in a drop-down list, a certain field is displayed on the layout? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, but I got it figured out. :-) It was actually really a trivial equals statement, and that was all! :)

Answer (score 0):

The calculation basically boiled down to just a single "equals" statement, or a bunch of them, simply singling out the value that would need to be selected in order to hide the layout objects I wanted hidden. Thanks for the help, guys! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted the new dropdown menus to stay shown even if many options were chosen in the first menu. I used the Pattern Count function (https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/10/fmp/en/html/func_ref3.33.73.html) to specify that if the answer to the last dropdown menu contained this optioned checked, the new menu would be shown by writing the following : Not PatternCount(table::variable;"text in one of the options")